# Is there a c# IDE for Android tablet?

Tags: c#, android, ide

This might be a silly question, but I'll ask it anyway. 
I'm on the road a lot or otherwise away from my computer, and i don't own a laptop sadly, and I'm still a beginner in programming.

I'm wondering if there is a c# IDE that would run on an android tablet, or will i have to stick to text editors while away from my PC?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use RDP/LogMeIn for your desktop ....

Comment: Sadly i don't have mobile net on my tablet, and in hungary wifi isn't all that common

Comment: Similar question (which is on topic for the Software Recommendation SE site) here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/709/c-ide-for-android It is in private beta right now, but will be public soon enough.

Comment: Check out c# to go: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gregshackles.csharptogo

Comment: That'S Awesome, thanks for telling me that :D

Comment: @JasonDown Thanks a lot, this one is really cool, really just what i've been looking for :D too bad i doN't have my tablet anymore :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A C# IDE doesn't exist on Android as far as i know, but you could have a look at [Touchqode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchqode.editor&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS50b3VjaHFvZGUuZWRpdG9yIl0.), which is a great code editor.

> Touchqode is a true mobile code editor that comes with syntax
>   highlighting, autocomplete and other features found in a desktop IDE

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Touchqode. I'm downloading it to my phone now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll download it and try it out!

Comment: So I checked it out and while it's not what I've been looking for it's way better then using a text editor, so thanks for that!